# Is it possible to deduce Poincaré duality from duality of polytopes?

Tags: convex-polytopes, duality, polyhedra, polytopes, poincare-duality

I'm having trouble understanding Poincaré duality, as it seems unmotivated. Here for instance:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14469/454016

Poincaré duality is explained through a duality of simplices and polyhedra. Since these are both two kinds of polytopes, and the general idea of "take the centers of all cells containing a given cell and form the convex closure" makes sense whenever you have polytopes with a clear center, I was thinking aboout whether this duality can be extended to a more complete duality between at least some polytopes. Are there any results in this direction?